# Is there a way to modify fonts in drop down menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, fonts, size, libreoffice-writer

I would like to modify the size of the applied fonts in Libreoffice Writer dropdown menu.

There is a font dropdown list (in the toolbar), just left of the font size dropdown menu.
For example, when I select a text and click on "Liberation Mono" in this menu, size 12 of "Liberation Mono" is applied, which I would like to be size 10 by default (I have to modify font size of selected text each and every time, which is tedious).

Is this possible to modify the default size of "Liberation Mono" (for example) in the font dropdown menu ?

Thanks.

Comment: An alternate could be to create a custom button in the toolbar to apply a font/size to a selected text. Is it possible ?